# Firebase Firestore writes / updates chunks per second

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created an inventory management web app where user can update unlimited documents. I understand the 500 writes rule and I divided user data into chunks. I decided that 60 writes per second is the best for my app. The question is
What is better:
**60 writes per second**
or
**20 writes per 330ms**
or maybe
**6 writes per 100ms**

What firestore likes? Many writes big break or less writes with small break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the [soft limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits):

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field:
>
> 500 per second

This limit is on **sustained** writes, so it doesn't really matter into what types of chunks you split them as long as over a longer period it doesn't exceed 500 writes to a sequential index per index per second.